# Two way data binding don't work in my Angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I just see a blank input box, when I should see the $scope.firstname value. Why does not this work?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Toto App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input ng-model="firstname">

</body>
</html>
```

myCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "John";
    });
```

Comment: it is "firstname" in the html and just "name" in the controller

Comment: Thanks i am so stupid

Comment: object name should be same. You are using $scope.name in controller but firstname in html.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `$scope.name = "John"` instead of `$scope.firstname = "John"`